# Pytest: Add mutually exclusive group in pytest_addoption hook

Tags: pytest

Is it any way how to add mutually exclusive group in `pytest_addoption` pytest hook? I tried code below but it raised next error - `AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'optparser'`

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    group = parser.optparser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('--foo', default=False)
    group.add_argument('--bar', default=False)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`pytest`'s option parser is an instance of `argparse.ArgumentParser`, not an `optparser`. Just remove `optparser`:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
```

See the docs for [mutual exclusion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

Comment: thanks for response, but it seems like even when i removed `optparser ` with `group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)` i got an error: `AttributeError: 'Parser' object has no attribute 'add_mutually_exclusive_group'
`

Comment: I don't think this will work. `pytest`'s `Parser` is a wrapper around the old `optparse` library, which was just hotfixed for `argparse` and never refactored properly. To add a mutually exclusive group, one would need to invoke the whole machinery for adding the `Argument`s to the `OptionGroup`s etc.

Comment: Exactly the other way around: pytest's `Parser` is based on argparse since [2.4.0](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/738b715655a6829cd82ed013655b88ee9106dc28/doc/en/announce/release-2.4.0.rst) and [mimics optparse](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/e7230691652ff31fcc1cd92e4f5bf080f386b681/src/_pytest/config/argparsing.py#L146).

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, but unfortunately still haven't found the solution yet